# Why doesn't torch pruning actually remove filters or weights?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pruning

I work with one architecture and trying to sparse it via prune. I wrote functions for pruning, here is one of them:

```
def prune_model_l1_unstructured(model, layer_type, proportion):
    for module in model.modules():
        if isinstance(module, layer_type):
            prune.l1_unstructured(module, 'weight', proportion)
            prune.remove(module, 'weight')
    return model

# prune model
prune_model_l1_unstructured(model, nn.Conv2d, 0.5)
```

It prunes some weights (change them to zeros). But *prune.remove* just deletes original weights and keeps zeros instead. Total amount of parameters still same (I checked it). The model's file (*model.pt*) size still the same too. And the model's "speed" still the same after it. I tried also global pruning and structured L1 pruning, results are the same. So how this can help to improve model's performance time? Why aren't the weights being removed and how to remove pruned connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

###### TLDR; PyTorch prune's function just works as a weight mask, that's all it does. There are no memory savings associated with using `torch.nn.utils.prune`.

---

As the documentation page for [`torch.nn.utils.prune.remove`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.utils.prune.remove.html) states:

> Removes the pruning reparameterization from a module and the pruning method from the forward hook.

In effect, this means it will remove the mask - that `prune.l1_unstructured` added - from the parameter. As a side effect, removing the prune will imply having zeros on the previously masked values but these won't stay as `0`s. In the end, PyTorch `prune` will only take more memory compared to not using it. So this is not actually the functionality you are looking for.

You can read more on [this comment](https://github.com/pytorch/tutorials/pull/605#issuecomment-585994076).

---

Here is an example:

```
>>> module = nn.Linear(10,3)
>>> prune.l1_unstructured(module, name='weight', amount=0.3)
```

The weight parameters are masked:

```
>>> module.weight
tensor([[-0.0000,  0.0000, -0.1397, -0.0942,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, -0.1452,
          0.0401,  0.1098],
        [ 0.2909, -0.0000,  0.2871,  0.1725,  0.0000,  0.0587,  0.0795, -0.1253,
          0.0764, -0.2569],
        [ 0.0000, -0.3054, -0.2722,  0.2414,  0.1737, -0.0000, -0.2825,  0.0685,
          0.1616,  0.1095]], grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
```

Here is the mask:

```
>>> module.weight_mask
tensor([[0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

Notice that when applying `prune.remove`, the pruning is removed. And, the masked values remain at zero but are *"unfrozen"*:

```
>>> prune.remove(module, 'weight')

>>> module.weight
tensor([[-0.0000,  0.0000, -0.1397, -0.0942,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, -0.1452,
          0.0401,  0.1098],
        [ 0.2909, -0.0000,  0.2871,  0.1725,  0.0000,  0.0587,  0.0795, -0.1253,
          0.0764, -0.2569],
        [ 0.0000, -0.3054, -0.2722,  0.2414,  0.1737, -0.0000, -0.2825,  0.0685,
          0.1616,  0.1095]], grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)
```

And the mask is gone:

```
>>> hasattr(module, 'weight_mask')
False
```

Comment: From pytorch tutorial page I got that  prune.remove() removes masks and original weights, not prunning. It replaces the original weights with the pruned ones, while the name remains the same. Therefore hasattr(module, 'weight_mask') outputs False. I tried to do so, and weight after prune.remove() seemed like they are pruned.

Comment: I don't really get you, did that solve your issue or you want clarifications?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I meant I think that you was wrong about prune.remove. Without removing, model has weight_orig and weight_mask, so the model size is even bigger than before pruning.

Comment: If you remove your prune, it will not keep the previously masked values to zero. Indeed pruning will take more memory since you are storing the mask. Read [this comment](https://github.com/pytorch/tutorials/pull/605#issuecomment-585994076) for more information. As of now, PyTorch prune's function just works as a weight mask, that's all. There are no memory savings associated with using `torch.nn.utils.prune`.

Comment: The answer's conclusion seems correct, but the first paragraph is misleading. It makes it sound like `prune.remove` undoes the pruning, which is not true. Your latest comment actually answers the question asked better than the answer itself.

Comment: I have edited my answer, thank you @GoodDeeds for the feedback.

Comment: Just as a follow up, if after calling prune.remove(), if the model is finetuned, will the zero values still be zero after the model training?